# BufferedReader not seeing end-of-file on StdIn when run under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, stdin

I'm reading standard input:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            for (;;) {
                var line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null) break;
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.err.println("Done.");
    }
```

If I use this in a terminal:

```
java TheClass </path/to/file
```

... it works: the program runs to completion.

But under Eclipse, if I set the same file as standard input (*Run Configurations>Common>Standard Input and output*), the program reads the file but it hangs after the last line until I enter a Ctrl-D in the console window (and then terminates normally).

Also under Eclipse, if I use the file directly (FileInputStream) the file is read to the end and the program terminates immediately.

Am I missing something or is this an Eclipse problem?

Using Eclipse 2020-06 on Linux with openjdk 11.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Eclipse bug: 513713 - In Run configuration when reading standard input from file, EOF is not issued at the end](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513713)