# BufferedReader stuck at last input line without ending the program

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader, system.in

I'm using `BufferedReader` to read data from `System.in` (a text file redirected context: `< file.txt`) then write it to the console. The problem is my program shows all lines except the last one and still works without doing any thing. If I manually end it it will write the final line.

This is my code:

```java
public void updateText() throws IOException {
    try {
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);         
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    String inputLine;
 
    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

         System.out.println(inputLine);

    }
    
    inputStreamReader.close();
    bufferedReader.close();
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work? Can you give any more details?

Comment: maybe  The problem is from eclipse as I'm actually using it.

Comment: Sounds like the last line in file.txt does not end with a newline.

Comment: Note that you can also read the text file using NIO, `Files.readAllLines(...)`, `Files.lines(...)`, `Files.readString(...)`. Just saying, in case you want an alternative to piping via `System.in`.

Comment: @MTilsted the absence of a end-of-line / new line at the end of the file should not prevent the buffered reader from detecting the end of file and reporting it as a new line. From the documentation : "Returns : A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an alternative way of **waiting on available data** (Ref.: [Java 11 - method BufferedReader.ready()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready())):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
            String line;
            // wait until data available
            while (!bufferedReader.ready()){
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Example output:**

```
Hello world 
Hello world 
Hello world
Hello world
```

Comment: OP wants to read from `System.in` (feeding a text file) and not from predefined string content. Downvoted as not useful.

Comment: @Zabuzard cleared, so make sure to recover your vote...

Comment: Cool. But did you also test it with a file that doesnt end with a newline symbol? Your code might run into the same problem than OPs original code.

Comment: Yeah i did tested it properly

Answer (score 1):

If this only occurs in Eclipse, your issue is most likely a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842862/bufferedreader-not-seeing-end-of-file-on-stdin-when-run-under-eclipse) and [bug 513713](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513713).

You don't need to read standard input line by line when you could simply transfer the data in one step, replacing the body of `updateText()`:

```
System.in.transferTo(System.out);
```